# How do I set a hover-off animation only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I wonder if there is a way that I can set a hover-off animation using CSS only. I have been looking for the answer on the Web, but those answers were all related to using transition instead of animation. Let me show you a bit of my code,

```
.foo:hover + .foo2 {
    animation: show .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    75% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}
```

It's pretty like a bubbling animation when it's hovered on. I want to reverse the keyframes so that when I hover off the .foo element, the reversed animation is played, just using CSS without transition.

This is the original code I'm currently working on. Hope it helps;

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="left">
            <div id="left-poster">
                <img src="./img/justice-league.jpg" alt="Justice league poster">
            </div>
            <div id="left-content">
                <div id="left-main">
                    <h2 class="title">JUSTICE LEAGUE</h2>
                    <p class="detail">You can't save the world alone.</p>
                    <p class="discounted-price">$28.00</p>
                    <p class="original-price">$44.99</p>
                </div>
                <div id="left-button">
                    <a href="#">BUY NOW</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
#left-poster {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                margin-top: -40px;
                padding: 20px;
                img {
                    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                }
                &:hover + #left-content {
                    animation: show .5s ease-in-out;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                }
            }
            #left-content {
                transform: scale(0);
                padding-top: 300px;
                margin-top: -300px;
                background-color: white;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                #left-main {
                    text-align: center;
                    .detail {
                        color: $default-gray;
                        margin-bottom: 20px;
                        font-size: .8rem;
                    }
                    .discounted-price {
                        color: $emphasized-green;
                        font-size: 1.2rem;
                    }
                    .original-price {
                        color: $default-gray;
                        text-decoration: line-through;
                        margin-bottom: 20px;
                    }
                }
                #left-button {
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    a {
                        display: block;
                        padding: 15px;
                        color: white;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        text-align: center;
                        background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
                        &:hover {
                            background-color: rgb(93, 93, 93);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML Code?

Comment: There is no "hover-off" in CSS